# Android/Eclipse & Xcode on Mac

Tags: android, xcode, eclipse, sdk

Sorry for the super dumb question, but is there any problem using the Android/Eclipse SDK on the same mac computer with Xcode? Is there anything special that needs to be done when installing or configuring the Android/Eclipse SDK on the same mac as Xcode?

Also, there seems to be a number of versions for Android/Eclipse. Which is the best and why? We would want our apps to be as backwardly compatible as possible, so please factor that in to any answers if it is relevant.

Thanks in advance for any help. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem installing Eclipse along with the Android SDK on a Mac computer which has XCode installed on it.  Though, there will be no integration at all between both and you will not be able to use the SDK on XCode.

As for which Eclipse version to pick, pick the oen that suits your needs.  If you're only going to use it for Android development then Java SE or classic should do.